# jquery-1.8.3 UI autocomplete select event not working with mouse click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, c#-4.0

```
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.minn.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<%-- <script src="../js/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>--%>
<script src="../js/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $(function () {
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
            initializer2();
        });

        function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
        }
        function EndRequest(sender, args) {
            initializer2();
        }
        function initializer2() {

            $('[id*=txtParty]').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1
            , source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Inventory/Invoice.aspx/GetParty") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        items = [];
                        map = {};
                        $.each(data.d, function (i, item) {
                            var id = item.split('-')[1];
                            var name = item.split('-')[0];
                            map[name] = { id: id, name: name };
                            items.push(name);
                        });
                        response(items);
                        $(".dropdown-menu").css("height", "auto");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });

            },
                updater: function (item) {
                    $('[id*=PartyID]').val(map[item].id);
                    return item;
                }
            });
    }
```

The code is working in the update panel but items are not select when using the mouse. So instead of depending on jquery UI to change the text of the textbox, which didn't happen if the user clicks with mouse.
I am able to use key up/down arrows to select menu items and once I hit return, the select event is fired and the console message is displayed.

Comment: You're libraries do not look right. It looks like you load jQuery twice and never load jQuery UI. Also what is `.typehead()`?

Comment: Link of the reference code is here :https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bootstrap-AutoComplete-TextBox-example-using-jQuery-TypeAhead-plugin-in-ASPNet-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx